# Clear the "Do not ask again" dialog in Gallery when changing Wallpapers

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, default-applications

As you might know, when you try to change the wallpaper on ICS (for your homescreen), the OS will ask if you want to set the same wallpaper to the lock screen, and the proper "do not ask again checkbox". By mistake, I pressed it, but I want it back now

Any way to achieve that?

BTW, I checked the "Clear Defaults" in the Gallery app - nothing. Using Android ICS 4.0.3

Comment: I don't get that option in my vanilla ICS. Which phone do you have?

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100. But I found out the problem — read below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a silly one. When you try to select a wallpaper you're given two choices: full wallpaper for the virtual desktop (option 1, scrollable wallpapers) and a fixed wallpaper (the second option).

If you select the **second** option, it will ask if you want to use the same wallpaper for the lock screen.

However, if you select the first one, it won't ask you anything (because it can't be set) — ths was the root of the problem.

I'm assuming that, if you do tap the "Do not show this dialog again" can be reset by tapping "Clear defaults" in the Gallery App.

Answer (score 0):

Gallery>clear cache and clear data> uncheck and recheck notifications.